# Dynamic StringGrid C++ Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder, stringgrid

I created a program in C++Builder 6 and I have a problem now.

I have 6 files: `Unit1.cpp`, `Unit1.h`, `Unit2.cpp`, `Unit2.h`, `Unit3.cpp`, `Unit3.h`.

`Unit1.cpp` is file for main form.

Problem : I want to create in Function `void __fastcall TForm3::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)` a `TStringGrid` which will be visible in `Unit1.cpp` and `Unit2.cpp`. Next click should create new `TStringGrid` with new name(previous exist)

I tried to fix my problem, I wrote some code, but it is not enough for me.
In `Unit1.h` I added:

```
void __fastcall MyFunction(TStringGrid *Grid1);
```

In `Unit1.cpp` I added:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::MyFunction(TStringGrid *Grid1)
{
        Grid1 = new TStringGrid(Form2);
        Grid1->Parent = Form2;
}
```

In `Unit3.cpp` I added:

```
#include "Unit1.h"
```

and the Button click function is:

```
 void __fastcall TForm3::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
     {
         Form1->MyFunction(Form1->Grid);  //Grid was declarated previous in Unit1.h
     }
```

Now when I used this method I dynamically create a `TStringGrid`, but only one. How do I create as many `TStringGrid`s (with unique names) as the number of times the button is pressed? (Now i must declarate `TStringGrid` in `Unit1.h`).

Comment: I suggest you name all of your forms, components, objects, and functions. Code where everything is "ClassName#" is not easy to maintain. I speak from experience with my company's codebase.

Comment: Which `unit.h` are you declaring `StringGrid` in, as you say in "Now i must declarate StringGrind in Unit.h"?

Comment: i declared in Unit 1.h

Comment: Okay, so do you want to have a different `TStringGrid` pointer for each one you create? Or do you want to re-use the same `TStringGrid` pointer from `Unit1.h` every time?

Comment: it may be difficult to understand what I wrote, but trying to do so that I can create any number  stringgrid with different names, which will be available for others file. e.g Stringgrid created in unit3.cpp, can be modify in Unit1.cpp -> in Unit1.cpp I can write data to rows StringGrid. Every created stringgrid should have diffrent name.

Comment: The exact thing you seem to have in mind is not possible, but I will post an answer soon proposing a couple of different options for you.

Comment: As another note, don't put `__fastcall` in a function signatures unless it is required. See this article: http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=63

Comment: You can set the name by doing `Grid1->Name = "hello";` after creating it

Comment: It's not clear what `Form1->Grid` is in this code, you never use it. (`MyFunction` does not update `Form1->Grid` since C++ is pass-by-value).

Comment: C++ is pass-by-value, but since it is a pointer being passed, the pointer can be used to modify the original object.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that your code *is* creating multiple `TStringGrid`s. It is just creating them all with the same dimensions in the same place on the form, so you only see the one on top.

--

What you want to be able to do (`Form1->dynamically_created_TStringGrid`) is not possible, but there are a couple of methods available to you to get similar behavior.

## The std::vector method

**Unit1.h**

```
#ifndef Unit1H
#define Unit1H
#include <vector>
//your other includes here

class PACKAGE Form1 : public TForm
{
__published:    //IDE-managed Components
    //your components here
private:
    /.../
    std::vector<TStringGrid *> SGridVec;
public:
    /.../
    AnsiString AddStringGrid(); 
    TStringGrid * GetStringGridByName(const AnsiString &Name);
    TStringGrid * GetStringGridByIndex(const unsigned int Index);
}
```

**Unit1.cpp**

```
AnsiString TForm1::AddStringGrid()
{
    SGridVec.push_back(new TStringGrid(Form2));    //Form2 is owner and handles memory management
    if (SGridVec.back())
    {
        SGridVec.back()->Parent = Form2;
        SGridVec.back()->Name = "some uniquely generated name";
        return SGridVec.back()->Name;
    }
    return "";  //add was unsuccessful
}

TStringGrid * TForm1::GetStringGridByName(const AnsiString &Name)
{
    for(std::vector<TStringGrid *>::iterator sgItr = SGridVec.begin();
        sgItr != SGridVec.end();
        ++sgItr)
    {
        if (*sgItr && (*sgItr)->Name == Name)
        {
            return *sgItr;
        }
    }
    return NULL;  //StringGrid with Name was not found
}

TStringGrid * TForm1::GetStringGridByIndex(const unsigned int Index)
{
    if (Index < SGridVec.size() && SGridVec.at(Index) != NULL)
        return SGridVec.at(Index);
    return NULL;  //StringGrid at Index was not found
}
```

Using this method you could call `AddStringGrid()` and store the return value. Then when you wanted to manipulate a given `TStringGrid` on `Form1` you would call `GetStringGridByName` and pass in the name of the `TStringGrid` you want to manipulate. You could also implement something very similar with a `std::map`, even as a `public` member.

## The FindChildControl method

**Unit1.h**

```
#ifndef Unit1H
#define Unit1H
#include <map>
//your other includes here

class PACKAGE Form1 : public TForm
{
__published:    //IDE-managed Components
    //your components here
public:
    /.../
    AnsiString AddStringGrid(); 
}
```

**Unit1.cpp**

```
AnsiString TForm1::AddStringGrid()
{
    TStringGrid *temp_ptr = new TStringGrid(Form2);    //Form2 is owner and handles memory management
    if (temp_ptr)
    {
        temp_ptr->Parent = Form2;
        temp_ptr->Name = "some uniquely generated name";
        return temp_ptr->Name;
    }
    return "";  //add was unsuccessful
}

void SomeClass::SomeFunctionThatUsesForm2sTStrinGrids(/.../)
{
    /.../  //some code
    TStrinGrid *temp_ptr = static_cast<TStringGrid *>(Form2->FindChildControl("name of control"));
    if (temp_ptr)
    {
        //do stuff to the string grid
    }
    /.../  //some other code
}
```

This version basically uses the `Parent -> Children` relationship to find the dynamically created `TStringGrid` instead of storing it in a `std::vector.` My gut says that it is slower and less safe than the `std::vector` method, but I don't have any proof. It also doesn't offer any simple, reliable way to get at the `StringGrid`s if you "forget" the unique names you gave them, while the `std::vector` lets you access them by index, or via an iterator if you make one available. There is `GetChildren`, but it does not look very intuitive to use.

--

At first I thought you would get a memory leak every time you call `TForm1::MyFunction`, but if I'm understanding the [Builder 6 documentation correctly](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/cbuilder6/EN/CB6_DevelopersGuide_EN.pdf), that is not the case:

> The TComponent class also introduces the concept of ownership that is
>   propagated throughout the VCL and CLX. Two properties support
>   ownership: Owner and Components. Every component has an Owner property
>   that references another component as its owner. A component may own
>   other components. In this case, all owned components are referenced in
>   the component’s Array property.
>
> A component's constructor takes a single parameter that is used to
>   specify the new component's owner. If the passed-in owner exists, the
>   new component is added to the owner's Components list. Aside from
>   using the Components list to reference owned components, this property
>   also provides for the automatic destruction of owned components. As
>   long as the component has an owner, it will be destroyed when the
>   owner is destroyed. For example, since TForm is a descendant of
>   TComponent, all components owned by the form are destroyed and their
>   memory freed when the form is destroyed. This assumes that all of the
>   components on the form clean themselves up properly when their
>   destructors are called.
>
> [.pdf page 53]

So even though you are assigning a `new`ed object to Grid1 every time you pass it in to that function, those objects are still owned by `Form2` and will be cleaned up when `Form2` is destructed.

All that said, you should be aware that, if you stick with the implementation you have posted in the OP, you won't be able to manipulate any of your string grids except for the last one unless you access them from `Form2->Array`.

Comment: If the answer satisfies you, please accept it by clicking the check-box. You are new here, so maybe you should go through the tour of the site: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I only want to create a stringgrid's( to keep data about cars entered by Edit fields)  during program is working. Cars are listed in Listbox1 and when i choose one filed and click button i see stringgrid with data  for the selected car

Comment: Ah, then in fact you do not want to create new `TStringGrid`s at all. I think you want to reuse the same `TStringGrid` but populate it with different data depending on which car is selected. I suggest you read up on the `TStringGrid` documentation to see how its elements can be modified.

Comment: @john: My answer answers the question you posted here. The question as you posted it is not going to draw the answer that your comment implies you are looking for. You will need to post a different question asking how to do that, **if and only if** you cannot figure it out for yourself from looking at the `TStringGrid` documentation.

Comment: i think about only one StringGrid but, I would have to always(when call StringGrid) read from file old date. If i have one stringgrid for one field I will read date  only one time  when program starts.

Comment: You could save the date when you load the file and then load it into the StringGrid from the variable instead of reloading from the file each time.

However, if you want to have a separate `TStringGrid` for each car model, I suggest using a `std::map`. The implementation would look similar to what I showed for `std::vector`, but your map would use some kind of key to differentiate the different kinds of car models and display the correct TStringGrid. You'll want to use something like `BringToFront`, `Parent` reassignment, or the Visible property to make the `TStringGrid` visible for the model.

Comment: Having a function return `AnsiString&` and then doing `return NULL;` causes undefined behaviour. The reference must refer to a valid string that exists. In fact the `return temp_ptr->Name;`also causes UB as that is a Property returning by value, so you are returning reference to a temporary object. I'd suggest just returning `TStringGrid *`.